# Weird DllNotFoundException on C# that only happens in a specific Visual Studio Solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, dllnotfoundexception

This may look weird, but I will explain the situation: I just started to work in a project with a company and cloned the C# Solution from their GitHub repository. One of the projects on the solution have a dependency in a third-party .NET Assembly, that is installed on the developer's machine (basically we install a Software and that Assembly is part of the installation, so we reference it from the location the Software is installed). When trying to instantiate a class from that DLL, I get a `DllNotFoundException` from another DLL, that is not a .NET Assembly. When I checked, that DLL is present in the same folder as the .NET Assembly referenced by the project. I am clueless of what may be the reason for this problem, but I did the two following tests:

- Created a new **Dummy Solution** with a **Dummy Console Application**, referenced that .NET Assembly to the project and tried to instantiate that class. Result: **It works!**
- Created a **Dummy Console Application** on the **same Solution** I cloned from GitHub. Result: **Same Exception!**

This leads me to think that the problem is on the Solution itself, but I have no idea what this problem might be, so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: 64bit vs 32bit issue? Check your build configuration vs the assembly supported cpu.

Comment: Both projects are set to run on "Any CPU"

Comment: OMG, I moved the solution to another location **on the same drive** and it worked!! I have no idea why....

Comment: @PedroMartinsTimóteodaCosta Is this a file system authorazation problem ? when u clone the project , maybe it's not setting the authoraztion correctly .

Comment: @John yes, maybe that's the problem. It kept working after I moved the solution back to it's original location.